# Sort/Order query result based on calculated fields

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of transactions in `Transactions` tab and in `Summary` I would like to summarize by tickers the performance. I am using `query` for grouping the data and using aggregate functions to calculate %-Win, %-Lost (see the link at the bottom with the sample spreadsheet):

Transaction tab:
[image: Sample Transaction tab]

```
=query({Transactions!B:B,Transactions!C:F}, 
  "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4),
  (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3),
  sum(Col5), 
  (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL 
  and 
     (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col2) 'Win', sum(Col4) '$-Win', 
    (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '%-Win', 
    count(Col3) 'Lost', sum(Col5) '$-Lost', 
    (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) '%-Lost'",1)
```

Sample of Summary tab:
[image: Sample of Summary tab]

but I was not able to obtain from the query by ticker: `Total Transactions`, `Net Gains`, `Exp. Value`(Expected Value), so I did use `Arrayformula`, and it works, the problem is that **I am not able to sort the result by expected value nor `Net Gain` (FUBO should be first)**. I was able to calculate percentage using a combination of aggregated functions, but not for the above additional calculations directly in the query.

I tried to use query clause `order by`: `sum(Col3)+sum(Col5)` (Net gains) but it doesn't work, it only returns a value when there are Win and Lost transactions.

Using `Data->Sort Range` doesn't provide the expected result either. Because there are different sources of data: the query and the result of `Arrayformula`.

I guess I would need to obtain all required calculated fields directly from the query and then to order by, or to find a way to sort the result combining the `query` and `Arrayformula` results. The clause `order by` works well for aggregated functions that are present in the select elements, but not when the sorting should happen based on a formula based on calculated columns.

Here you can find a sample file from my real situation:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xrDSWGJVIsWD6fvAOdMOZkw2rEY9lGPZRb_Ww_nC7YQ/edit?usp=sharing

**Note**: A possible solution would be to combine all the results into one `sort` statement, but I am not able to make it work

```
=sort({
query({Transactions!B2:B,Transactions!C2:F}, "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4), (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3), sum(Col5), (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) group by Col1 label count(Col2) '', sum(Col4) '', (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '', count(Col3) '', sum(Col5) '', (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) ''",0),
ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(ISBLANK(A2:A)), B2:B+E2:E,)),
ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(ISBLANK(A2:A)), C2:C+F2:F,)),
ARRAYFORMULA(if(not(ISBLANK(A2:A)), (C2:C)*(D2:D) + (F2:F)*(G2:G),))
},10, FALSE)
```

In the same way avoiding using `Arrayformula` using two `query` statements, doesn't work:

```
=sort({
query({Transactions!B2:B,Transactions!C2:F}, "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4), (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3), sum(Col5), (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) group by Col1 label count(Col2) '', sum(Col4) '', (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '', count(Col3) '', sum(Col5) '', (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) ''",0),
query(query({Transactions!B2:B,Transactions!C2:F}, "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4), (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3), sum(Col5), (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) group by Col1 label count(Col2) '', sum(Col4) '', (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '', count(Col3) '', sum(Col5) '', (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) ''",0),"select Col2+Col5 label Col2+Col5 ''",0),
query(query({Transactions!B2:B,Transactions!C2:F}, "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4), (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3), sum(Col5), (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) group by Col1 label count(Col2) '', sum(Col4) '', (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '', count(Col3) '', sum(Col5) '', (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) ''",0), "select Col3+Col6 label Col3+Col6 ''",0),
query(query({Transactions!B2:B,Transactions!C2:F}, "select Col1, count(Col2),sum(Col4), (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))), count(Col3), sum(Col5), (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) where Col1 is not NULL and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null) group by Col1 label count(Col2) '', sum(Col4) '', (count(Col2)/(count(Col2)+count(Col3))) '', count(Col3) '', sum(Col5) '', (count(Col3)/(count(Col3)+count(Col2))) ''",0), "select Col3*Col4+Col6*Col7 label Col3*Col4+Col6*Col7 ''",0)
},10, FALSE)
```

Doesn't give all the result values for `Net Gain` and `Exp. Value`
[image: Combining all queries together]

As you can see it only provides `Net Gains` and `Exp. Value` where are `Win` and `Lost` values on the same row.

Comment: Would you be willing to consider a programmatic approach for this?

Comment: @ale13 the thing is that I don´t understand why the query doesn't work as I expected. I put all the conditions I need and in some cases, the aggregate function works as expected like in `%-Win`, `%-Lost`, but not for additional fields I need. At least understanding that, I would consider other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fill the blanks with `0`.

```
=SORT(QUERY(query(ArrayFormula({Transactions!B:B,
 IF(Transactions!C:F="",0, Transactions!C:F)}), 
  "select  Col1, sum(Col2),sum(Col4),
    (sum(Col2)/(sum(Col2)+sum(Col3))), 
    sum(Col3), sum(Col5), (sum(Col3)/(sum(Col3)+sum(Col2))) 
    where  Col1 is not NULL and NOT (Col2 = 0 and Col3 = 0) group by Col1",1),
 "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7,Col2+Col5, 
    Col3+Col6,Col3*Col4+Col6*Col7 
    label Col2 'Win',Col3 '$-Win', Col4 '%-Win', Col5 'Lost', 
    Col6 '$-Lost', Col7 '%-Lost', Col2+Col5 'Total Transactions', 
    Col3+Col6 'Net Gains',Col3*Col4+Col6*Col7 'Exp. Value'",1),
10,FALSE)
```

**Notes:**

1. The condition: `NOT (Col2 = 0 and Col3 = 0)`ensures to exclude transactions that were not sold, i.e. `Win =0` and `Lost = 0`
2. The condition: `IF(Transactions!C:F="",0, Transactions!C:F)`ensures empty values are replaces by `0`to ensure the agregate SQL functions work as expected

Comment: Thanks @idfurw, just to confirm is this the solution provided on the tab: Sheet 4 from my sample file?

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, but then I realized that it is not correct, for example, FUBO has zero losses, but the result shows 3 losses, therefore the %-Win, %-Lost and expected value is not correct. This happens when there are 0-losses or 0-wins.

Comment: Modified. `count` should be changed to `sum` because the blanks are filled.

Comment: I corrected your solution to provide the expected result and added some explanation why it was not correct. I consider your solution is correct now based on the modification. Thanks

Comment: @DavidLeal instead of doing a major edit to correct this incorrect answer, you could write your own correct answer.

Comment: @rhavelka I have seen this before, per my opinion it is not fair, the idea came from the first answer, it required some changes I wanted to give him credit. Approval is pending, if it doesn't get approval, then I will add the final solution as a separate post.

Comment: I only modified the essential components, that a meaningless comparison ` and (Col2 is not NULL or Col3 is not Null)` is left there. However, I cannot get what is wrong with my updated answer.

Comment: @idfurw I updated your solution, for some reason the last change was not taken into account. Now it works as expected to remove no sold transactions (Win or Lost are both zero) from the Transactions tab. I also simplified the `IF` condition. in David.Leal Testing tab you can find the solution. Please let me know. Thanks